# UWP How to add <ResouceDictionnary> and <Local> into <Application.Resources> in App.xaml

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In App.xaml, I need to add some <local:MyClass x:key="xx"> into Application.Resources.
Because Application.Resources already have ResourceDictionary, so I get an error "The property "Resource" can only be set once".

★How to add many resource into Application.Resources

If I move local into ResourceDictionary, build OK, but when runs, app will be stoped in App.g.i.cs

```
public void InitializeComponent()
 {
      ...
      #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
                  UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
                  {
                      if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                  };
      #endif
 }
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <local_viewmodels:MyViewModel x:Key="SharedMyViewModel"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="Choose File" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChooseFileCommand}" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.FileNames}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class UserControlList : UserControl
{
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    public UserControlList()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = Application.Current.Resources["SharedMyViewModel"] as MyViewModel;
    }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private int count = 0;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileNames { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ICommand ChooseFileCommand { get; }

    private bool CanExecuteCommand()
    {
        if (count > 3)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ChooseFileCommand = new RelayCommand(ChooseFile, CanExecuteCommand);
    }

    private void ChooseFile()
    {
        count++;
        FileNames.Add(count.ToString());
    }
}
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = () => true;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use `SharedMyViewModel`, could you please provide a [mcve] to help us further check the problem for you?

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, Thanks for your reply.  I provided the source code.

Comment: But firstly, is App.xaml code OK?  or <local_viewmodels> must be in <ResourceDictionary>

Comment: I add `<Local: MyViewModel X: Key = "SharedmyViewModel"/>` to `<ResourceDictionary>`, everything work. Is `local_viewmodels` added by UWP Class library?

Comment: My problem is, If <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> and <Local: MyViewModel X: Key = "SharedmyViewModel"/> at the same time  in a <ResourceDictionary>, It causes an error when run.

Comment: You can create an any style xaml, then add it into app xaml like  App.xaml above.

Comment: About local_viewmodels, MyViewModel in another namespace, so I using that namespace in App.xaml and named it as local_viewmodels. Everything is OK if only has <local....> In <ResourceDictionary>

Comment: I still can't reproduce your behavior, maybe you can create a blank UWP project and try to see if the error still occurs. [My App.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEZoM.png), and it can run normally. The effect is that clicking the button will add a column to the list.

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, I clean solution and rebuild, It works!  I'm really sorry for taking you some time to debug. I will test again with many <local resource>, and if has any error like this, I will contact again.